# Extract patches from list of images using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

How we can extract patches if we have a list of images.

example:

```
def get_train_images():
    image_list = glob(FLAGS.train_path + '/*.jpg')
    #extract_patch
```

Want to do something like this:
For example, I did this for only 1 image, but I wanted to do the same task for 100 images.

sample image(s): [image: sample image]

output image of sample image(s): [image: Output images]

I have a list of images and want to extract patches from an image and save them in another list. And that list can be overwritten.

Comment: What's a "patch"? Please include sample inputs and expected output. What do you want to do with the "patches"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of two images in a list. The image patches are extracted for each image, and the end result is an array of 4 patches per image, hence the shape `(2, 4, 4, 3)` of `patched_images`, where 2 is the number of samples, 4 is the number of patches per image, and `(4, 4, 3)` is the shape of each patch image.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

images = [tf.random.normal((16, 16, 3)), tf.random.normal((16, 16, 3))]

patched_images = []
for img in images:
  image = tf.expand_dims(np.array(img), 0)
  patches = tf.image.extract_patches(images=image,
                          sizes=[1, 4, 4, 1],
                          strides=[1, 4, 4, 1],
                          rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                          padding='VALID')
  patches = [tf.reshape(patches[0, i, i], (4, 4, 3)) for i in range(4)]
  patched_images.append(np.asarray(patches))

patched_images = np.asarray(patched_images)
print(patched_images.shape)

axes=[]
fig=plt.figure()
patched_image = patched_images[0] # plot patches of first image
for i in range(4):
    axes.append( fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i + 1) )
    subplot_title=("Patch "+str(i + 1))
    axes[-1].set_title(subplot_title)  
    plt.imshow(patched_image[i, :, :, :])
fig.tight_layout()    
plt.show()
```

```
(2, 4, 4, 4, 3)
```

[image]

If you have different image sizes and still want to extract 4x4 patches regardless of the size of the images, try this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

images = [tf.random.normal((16, 16, 3)), tf.random.normal((24, 24, 3)), tf.random.normal((180, 180, 3))]

patched_images = []
for img in images:
  image = tf.expand_dims(np.array(img), 0)
  patches = tf.image.extract_patches(images=image,
                          sizes=[1, 4, 4, 1],
                          strides=[1, 4, 4, 1],
                          rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                          padding='VALID')
  patches = [tf.reshape(patches[0, i, i], (4, 4, 3)) for i in range(4)]
  patched_images.append(np.asarray(patches))
```

Comment: It is working fine for different dimensions too.

Comment: need help with other problems. I am not getting that.

Comment: i can explain bit more @docs